# swiftmailer transport config not loaded

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I have troubles with swiftmailer on my projet (symfony 2.8)

When i create the transporter myself, it works but when i try to load the swiftmailer config, it fails.

so i looked into the $mailer variable.

When i do :

```
$transporter = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('myWebMail.com', 465, 'ssl')
        ->setUsername('user@test.com')
        ->setPassword('secret');
$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);
```

I can see that the conf is loaded when i debug :

```
Swift_Mailer::__set_state(array(
   '_transport' => 
  Swift_SmtpTransport::__set_state(array(
     '_handlers' => 
    array (
      'AUTH' => 
      Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler::__set_state(array(
         '_authenticators' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_CramMd5Authenticator::__set_state(array(
          )),
          1 => 
          Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_LoginAuthenticator::__set_state(array(
          )),
          2 => 
          Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_PlainAuthenticator::__set_state(array(
          )),
          3 => 
          Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_NTLMAuthenticator::__set_state(array(
          )),
          4 => 
          Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_XOAuth2Authenticator::__set_state(array(
          )),
        ),
         '_username' => 'user@test.com',
         '_password' => 'secret',
         '_auth_mode' => NULL,
         '_esmtpParams' => 
        array (
        ),
      )),
      ...
```

But when i do :

```
$mailer = $this->container->get('swiftmailer.mailer');
```

i have this :

```
Swift_Mailer::__set_state(array(
   '_transport' => 
  Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport::__set_state(array(
     '_handlers' => 
    array (
      'AUTH' => 
      Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler::__set_state(array(
         '_authenticators' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_CramMd5Authenticator::__set_state(array(
          )),
          1 => 
          Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_LoginAuthenticator::__set_state(array(
          )),
          2 => 
          Swift_Transport_Esmtp_Auth_PlainAuthenticator::__set_state(array(
          )),
        ),
         '_username' => 'user@test.com',
         '_password' => 'secret',
         '_auth_mode' => NULL,
         '_esmtpParams' => 
        array (
        ),
      )),
    ),
```

I deleted the app/cache folder
In my parameter.yml i have :

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: myWebMail.com
mailer_port: 465
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_user: user@test.com
mailer_password: secret
```

And in my config.yml :

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: default_mailer
    mailers:
        default_mailer:
            transport: "%mailer_transport%"
            host:      "%mailer_host%"
            username:  "%mailer_user%"
            password:  "%mailer_password%"
```

What did i miss ?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in your app_prod/dev who could override this? you are missing the key `encryption: %mailer_encryption%` and  `port: %mailer_port%` in the config

Comment: encryption was missing : thanks a lot